# Regex to find week date

Tags: regex

We're receiving a file from a customer which we need to read and save some values into our ERP-System.

the customer sends us a date in a week format like: `201814` this would mean the 14th week of the year 2018

the customer sends this date never in the same place in the file, so the only way i think I can get this date, is by searching the string in the file by regex.

My Regex should probably consist of the following conditions:

- the length of the string is always 6 characters
- all characters are nummeric values
- the string always starts with `20`
- the last two values have to be between `01` and `53`

what would the perfect regex for this be? there are many other "nummeric-only" values in the file, that's why i need to be so specific

I know I can do the length condition like this `{1,6}` and I know that `[0-9]` matches all digits from zero to nine, but I can't see how I can restrict 01 to 53.

Can someone help me with my regex? thanks a lot!

Comment: last two value means? 2018xx this xx?

Comment: You have to separate each match `\b20[0-9]{2}(?:0[1-9]|[1-4][0-9]|5[123])\b`

Comment: @SimonS you didn't mention what flavour of regex ? i.e. which language ?

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman it's C#

Comment: @SimonS btw I have provided an answer considering your conditions, does that solve your problem ?

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman yes, it works! I will accept your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
\b20\d{2}(?:0[1-9]|[1-4]\d|5[0-3])(?!\d)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XFlBMp/6)

Explanation:

1. `\b` word boundary start of string indiciator
2. `20` literaly must start with 20
3. `\d{2}` followed by any two digits
4. `(?:` non capturing group starts here
5. `0[1-9]` means 01 to 09

   or
6. `[1-4]\d` means 10 to 49

   or
7. `5[0-3]` means 50-53
8. `)` end of non capturing group
9. `(?!\d)` negative lookahead to ensure the entire match is not followed
   by a digit. The entire regex is formed such a way that you should not need to measure 6 digits; as if it is not 6 digit then the above conditions won't be met.

Comment: you can start and end your expression with \b to verify it is a word, then you don't need the (?!\d)

Comment: well I know that , but suppose in a real world if an input comes up like 201852ZZZZ accidentally.. even then that would work isn't it ? But, you may think then I should also consider doing the same in the beginning... that is a point... you may call me a bit lazy here :) ! But I didn't do that because, I was unsure whether the op's preferred language support lookbehind or not.. which I just found out  as supported

Answer (score 0):

Use This: `(20)\d{2}([1-4][0-9]|[0][1-9]|[5][1-3])`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ilXS66/3)